# jQuery expand DIV on click and replace contents

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an expandable rollout when the user clicks on a tab.

It is basically 2 rows of tabs, each with their own colour and when the user clicks on one of them a hidden DIV should animate out.
I Don't assume that this would be to hard to do, but the problem comes when the user clicks on a different tab when one is already open. Then the new content has to overtake the existing contents place.

this is what I have so far;
http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/W3afW/

---

```
                     The 4 images represent what should happen
                      when you click on tab 01, 02, 03 and 08
```

Comment: You are going to want to make sure you use unique `id` attributes for each element.  I see you have multiple `id="tab_text"`... Just a tip :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W3afW/2/ ???

Comment: I have just added 4 images so you can see what I want to end up with. The 4 images represent what should happen when you click on tab 01, 02, 03 and 08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L5P2Y/)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $cont;    
    function tgl_conts(){
        $('.content').stop().animate({height: 0},1200);
        $cont.stop().animate({height:210},1200);
    }
    
    $('.tab').on('click',function(){
        var tabClass=$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        $cont = $('.'+tabClass+':not(.tab)');
        var h = ($cont.height() === 0) ? tgl_conts() :  ( $cont.stop().animate({height: 0},1200) );  
    });

});
```

Take care!!! I removed all your ID's (CSS also), and added separated classes for your duplicates:

`.turquoise` and `.turquoise2`
same for `.pink` `.pink2` 'cause you have 2 elements of each, and we have to distinguish them!

**P.S: nice usability! great expression, nice idea bro!**

**EDIT**
Added setup for 'speed' (animation time) and easings for the jQuery UI library:

### *[demo with easing](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/L5P2Y/1/)*

Comment: Absolutely Fabulous!!!
Where would I add the javascript to edit the method of animation?

Comment: If you have some problems in understanding the script, please let me know!

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen how you mean 'method of amination?' the speed?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to use easing? And maybe even adjust the speed?

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen Sure! But you have to use the jQuery UI library: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/L5P2Y/1/ || You'll see, I added 2 vars at the top you can adjust as you wish.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome!!!

Would it be difficult to fade on a 50% black overlay to the tabs that aren't active? So that all tabs are dimmed apart from the one that is active?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10371/discussion-between-craig-jonathan-kristensen-and-roko-c-buljan)

Answer (score 0):

Ok...So basically what you want to do is have a `<div>` element within each one of your tabs.  When the user clicks one of the tabs, jQuery will make sure that no other "pop out" div elements are visible and then display the corresponding div.

I'll take 3 tabs as an example -

```
<div class="tab" id="pink">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160" width="160" height="160" />
    <span class="tab_text">TITLE 01</span>
    <div class="pop-out">Some pink information</div>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="turquoise">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160" width="160" height="160" />
    <span class="tab_text">TITLE 02</span>
    <div class="pop-out">Some turquoise information</div>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="yellow">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160" width="160" height="160" />
    <span class="tab_text">TITLE 03</span>
    <div class="pop-out">Some yellow information</div>
</div>
```

Notice that they every time I use an `id` attribute they are **each** unique. The `id` attribute should always have a unique value as opposed to the `class` attribute which you can see can have the same values. `class="pop-out"`

- `pop-out` will be our way of identifying all of the pop-out div elements
- when the user clicks the tab, we'll add an additional `sel` class (short for selected).  So that we can track what div was last open (if there was any) and make sure to close it before opening a new one.

Now, lets say we want the trigger to be the entire tab.  Anywhere the user clicks on it will trigger the pop-out.

```
$(".tab").on('click',function(){
  $("div.pop-out.sel").fadeOut().removeClass('sel'); // this will hide the last selected div and remove its selected class
  $(this).find("div.pop-out").fadeIn().addClass('sel'); // this will display the div of the element the user clicked and add the selected class.
}
```

<sub>Obviously you can substitute any animation you desire.</sub>

Now we can also track what tab is open by using -

```
$("div.pop-out.sel").closest("div.tab");
```

This will return the parent of the pop-out div that is currently being displayed.  Remember to test if a selected div  *actually* exists first :)

Comment: This will just expand the tab? I would like the content that is revealed to look like the images that I have attached above. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is - you can still use my solution.  Instead of having one div for each tab, just have two "pop-out" divs.  One under each row.  If you click one of the first 5 then you display the top one.  if its more than 5 then you display the bottom one.

Comment: I'm not having any luck when I paste your solution into my jsfiddle.
Though I have made a very long and sloppy code that does do something I the right direction.
http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/W3afW/4/
The only thing that need fixing now is that they should only expand on CLICK instead of HOVER, and when one is clicked it should test if another one is open and close it first.

Comment: Ok - well, If you are asking me to write you a complete solution that you can just copy and paste then I'm afraid [that's not going to happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172936).